# Identify and trigger event(s) on a "dropdown/selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm primarily a BI report developer and a complete JS/JQuery novice.  I have a requirement to default one of the "dropdown/selector" values when the page loads.  Unfortunately, there is no out of the box functionality that can set a default value in the tool (Microstrategy) that I am using.

Thus far, I have been able to default the text.  However, there are events that are tied to values in the "dropdown/selector" that will refresh the other page elements. I have been unable to identify or trigger any event that will refresh these other page elements.

HTML snippet of the "dropdown/selector":

```
    <div id="*lW97AC0343C8A843F7803C7F5C3705A2C7*kW03B8BE5F89014A668C84F3702E0B0B73*x1*t1587427161911" k="W03B8BE5F89014A668C84F3702E0B0B73" class="mstrmojo-DocSelector vi-DocSelector" nm="YearMonth (PSPI)" title="" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font: bold 9pt Arial; display: block; height: 35px; width: 223px;">
     <div class="filter" style="display: none;" />
     <div class="wait" style="display:none;z-index:100;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%" />
     <div class="content" style="overflow-x: hidden; height: 35px; width: 223px;">
      <div id="mstr559" style="text-align: left; font: bold 9pt Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: block; height: 35px; width: 223px;" class="mstrmojo-ui-Pulldown mstrmojo-ui-SearchablePulldown" onmousedown="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr559','mousedown', self, event)" onclick="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr559','click', self, event)">
         <div class="mstrmojo-ui-Pulldown-text  hasEditableText" title="" style="">201911</div>
         <div class="container">
            <div id="mstr560" class="mstrmojo-PopupList ctrl-popup-list mstrmojo-scrollbar-host" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1" onclick="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','click', self, event)" ondblclick="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','dblclick', self, event)" onmouseover="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','mouseover', self, event)" onmouseout="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','mouseout', self, event)" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','contextmenu', self, event)" onkeydown="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('mstr560','keydown', self, event)">
               <div class="mstrmojo-popupList-scrollBar mstrmojo-scrollNode" style="overflow: hidden;">
                  <div class="" style="">
                     <div class="item " idx="0" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        202003
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="1" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        202002
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="2" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        202001
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="3" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201912
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="4" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201911
                     </div>
                     <div class="item selected" idx="5" style="font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201910
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="6" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201909
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="7" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201908
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="8" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201907
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="9" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201906
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="10" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201905
                     </div>
                     <div class="item " idx="11" style="color: #000;font:bold 9pt 'Arial'" title="">
                        <span class="sp-highlight" />
                        201904
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="mstrmojo-scrolltrack vertical">
                  <div class="mstrmojo-scrollbar vertical" />
               </div>
               <div class="mstrmojo-scrolltrack horizontal">
                  <div class="mstrmojo-scrollbar horizontal" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My /JQuery script:

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.js";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

$(document).ready(function(){

// works
$("div[k='W03B8BE5F89014A668C84F3702E0B0B73'] .mstrmojo-ui-Pulldown-text").text('201911');


// works
// $('div[k="W03B8BE5F89014A668C84F3702E0B0B73"] div[idx="0"]').addClass('selected');

// does not work
$('#mstr599.mstrmojo-ui-Pulldown.mstrmojo-ui-SearchablePulldown').trigger('onmousedown');
$('#mstr599.mstrmojo-ui-Pulldown.mstrmojo-ui-SearchablePulldown').trigger('onclick');

// there are 2 other events associated with the mstr599 element: mouseout and mouseover
});

</script>
```

What I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the `on` prefix of each trigger event. ex. `.trigger('click')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and still doesn't work.

Comment: Regardless, keep it as I have [suggested](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Explain what *"refresh"* means? The *"values"* are those numbers: 201904, 201905, etc.? All events bound to `#mstr559` and `#mstr560` are multiple on-event attributes that trigger the same event handler `mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent()`. Find the Object, or class Function, that `mstmojo` is and/or its method `.captureDOMEvent()` . The strategy to hack the client-side jQuery doesn't look promising. You'll most likely need administrative privileges to schedule refreshing or to disable the cache.

Comment: You should do a little more [research](https://doc-archives.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.8/BasicReporting/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/BasicReporting/BRAccessingData.htm)

Comment: Yes, the values are 201904, 201905, etc. - basically YYYYMM.  When the user selects one of these values from the dropdown, the information contained in graphs and other visuals on the page is updated to show the numbers specific to the month selected.

Comment: I agree this is not an elegant or ideal solution, but I have confirmed through official Microstrategy sources that currently there is no out-of-the-box solution to display a preferred default value (in my case, latest month) in the dropdown when the user opens the report, i.e., when the page is first loaded.

Comment: I thought MicroStrategy was more robust than what I just recently learned. Not a real time tool I'd say. Good luck, sir.